# Paypal account is a barrier

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms, payments

I am currently unemployed and have a family to support. I have been looking for some freelance work that includes content writing and social media marketing.
I have been searching Internet and came across few websites that conduct online surveys that pay you for participating. But in order to withdraw the money, a paypal accowis needed. I live in a country where there is no concept of paypal. 
What should I know? I am in real need.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of another methods available if paypal is not accessible for you.

You can use any of following :

1 - [Skrill](https://www.skrill.com/)

2 - Western Union if client is ready to pay directly into your bank account

3 - PayU Money [For India Only]

Comment: Can someone guide me about using payza?

Answer (score 1):

Find another job, or ask if they can pay you via another method. There's a reason they are wanting to user PayPal, and if you can't use it, you can't come to an arrangement around that. Change the terms, and ask if they can pay you by cheque or money order or Western Union or bank draft or cash or BitCoins, or... or... or...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [skrill](https://www.skrill.com/en/home/) , it is almost available for every country. You just have to make your account on it with your banking info. And ask client to pay you on skrill.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest by using [Payoneer](https://www.payoneer.com/). Register, they will send you a Mastercard and then you can take money in any ATM.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Payoneer.com as @The1stLeo suggested as well as the following:

- Open a Paypal account: Make sure to register as if you were living in the United States.
- Open a Payoneer account (you can do it through Elance/Upwork), and wait until they send you the Mastercard debit card.
- Once you have the card, link it to your Paypal account (you will need to confirm the card through a small 1 dollar charge they will make you).
- Once you receive funds through Paypal, you can use the "Withdraw funds" option and send them to your Payoneer card.
- Use the Payoneer card to withdraw from the ATMs in your country.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would violate PayPal's T&C, and close the account and freeze any and all funds that went through PayPal.

Comment: I can say, based on many people I know that have opened a US account, that they haven't had any trouble... anyway, do as you consider necessary.

Comment: Paypal might verify the identity of the card holder and it will need to match the Payoneer's details. It might have worked a few years ago though but I'm not sure anymore since I think Paypal now requires to see IDs. It's possible it works on basic accounts with less than $1000 transactions though. Anyway, that could work although it's borderline legal. One thing for sure, you don't want to have to contact the Paypal customer support (it's probably easier to meet Santa Claus actually heehee!) But Payoneer itself is great. And Stripe is also another payment method that wasn't mentioned anywhere